# Can not login after "yum remove *fonts*"

Tags: linux, centos

By mistake I did `yum remove *fonts*`.
Now I can't log in my pc with centos OS.
Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Boot into single-user mode](http://www.uptimemadeeasy.com/linux/boot-centos-into-single-user-mode/) and run `yum install *fonts*`.

Comment: `yum install *fonts*` would probably install a lot more than required. After booting into single-user mode, just run `yum history undo last` to reinstall back what you have removed.